# Update similar values in separated row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
##############################################
# ID # TAG 1 # TAG 2 # TAG 3 # TAG 4 # TAG 5 #
#--------------------------------------------#
#  1 #  A    #   B   #    C  #   D   #   E   #
#  2 #  B    #   G   #    H  #   J   #   K   #
##############################################
```

Lets say i need to pick all tags with the value "B" and make it "".

Question: What would be the query to do that?

Thanks

Comment: "Best" as in...? Fastest? Most readable? ...?

Comment: You have to check every colmn for containing B :/ i See no shorter solution if you cant change the table-structures

Comment: As your model is far from optimal, I wouldn't care too much about building a suboptimal query to achieve something you clearly won't do all the time. Looking for "best" solutions, start by enhancing your model.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson a working query for start would be great :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant and a working query? can you provide?.

Comment: SO is not a "give me the query" kind of girl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several queries:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable SET TAG1 = '' WHERE TAG1 = 'B';
UPDATE yourTable SET TAG2 = '' WHERE TAG2 = 'B';
UPDATE yourTable SET TAG3 = '' WHERE TAG3 = 'B';
UPDATE yourTable SET TAG4 = '' WHERE TAG4 = 'B';
UPDATE yourTable SET TAG5 = '' WHERE TAG5 = 'B';
```

One query:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable SET
    TAG1 = CASE WHEN TAG1 = 'B' THEN '' ELSE TAG1 END,
    TAG2 = CASE WHEN TAG2 = 'B' THEN '' ELSE TAG2 END,
    TAG3 = CASE WHEN TAG3 = 'B' THEN '' ELSE TAG3 END,
    TAG4 = CASE WHEN TAG4 = 'B' THEN '' ELSE TAG4 END,
    TAG5 = CASE WHEN TAG5 = 'B' THEN '' ELSE TAG5 END
-- the where clause is optional, but prevents updating every row
WHERE TAG1 = 'B' OR TAG2 = 'B' OR TAG3 = 'B' OR TAG4 = 'B' OR TAG5 = 'B'
```

Nothing optimal, but both ways should work.

From a more general point of view, consider building a table containing the id and the other related data (I guess that id refers to something) and build a tag table referencing it:

**mainTable**

```sql
id | other
----------
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
```

**tags**

```sql
id | pos | val
--------------
 1 |   1 | A
 1 |   2 | B
 1 |   3 | C
 1 |   4 | D
 1 |   5 | E
 2 |   1 | B
 2 |   2 | G
 2 |   3 | H
 2 |   4 | J
 2 |   5 | K
```

This way, you have a normalized model, and can achieve your requirement using:

```sql
UPDATE tags SET val = '' WHERE val = 'B'
```

Comment: yap that would be perfect if the table was made that way...
The first option is the right one! Thanks

Comment: @rdn87 I provided both approaches: one query or several. What's your point ?

Comment: Nothing but SO not a tutorial.. I think you have to show the best approach but you can do with a single query

Comment: @rdn87 What makes you think one query has to be a better approach than several ? AFAIK, this could depend on a lot of parameters that are not provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE myTable
 SET `TAG 1` = IF(`TAG 1` = 'B', '', `TAG 1`),
     `TAG 2` = IF(`TAG 2` = 'B', '', `TAG 2`),
     `TAG 3` = IF(`TAG 3` = 'B', '', `TAG 3`),
     `TAG 4` = IF(`TAG 4` = 'B', '', `TAG 4`),
     `TAG 5` = IF(`TAG 5` = 'B', '', `TAG 5`);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this query for your case ([SELECT WITH CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)):

```
SELECT ID,
  CASE TAG_1
    WHEN 'B' THEN ''
    ELSE TAG_1 
  END as TAG_1,
  CASE TAG_2
    WHEN 'B' THEN ''
    ELSE TAG_2 
  END as TAG_2,
  CASE TAG_3
    WHEN 'B' THEN ''
    ELSE TAG_3 
  END as TAG_3,
  CASE TAG_4
    WHEN 'B' THEN ''
    ELSE TAG_4 
  END as TAG_4,
  CASE TAG_5
    WHEN 'B' THEN ''
    ELSE TAG_5 
  END as TAG_5
FROM table;
```

OR Update with [IF Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html):

```
UPDATE table
 SET TAG_1 = IF(TAG_1 = 'B', '', TAG_1),
     TAG_2 = IF(TAG_2 = 'B', '', TAG_2),
     TAG_3 = IF(TAG_3 = 'B', '', TAG_3),
     TAG_4 = IF(TAG_4 = 'B', '', TAG_4),
     TAG_5 = IF(TAG_5 = 'B', '', TAG_5);
```